# Scroll bar position using AM charts

Tags: charts, amcharts

I am trying to place scroll bar to position bottom but I am not able to set. I have specified position like ,

```
 "chartScrollbar": {
    "graph": "g1",
    "position" : "bottom",
  },
```

I am not able to set its position. Please some one suggest whats going wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/g1gfjjuv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **don't** use cdnjs to load AmCharts. The files there are extremely outdated and some features such as `valueScrollbar` and scrollbar positioning are not available in 3.13.0. Update your links to use the CDN directly from amcharts, i.e. www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js, etc, in order to use the latest version.

That said, there is no `position` property for the `chartScrollbar`. You have to use [`oppositeAxis`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartScrollbar#oppositeAxis). You correctly set it to false to set it on the bottom, however it is not available in 3.13, so updating the script paths to use the latest version of AmCharts will fix the issue.

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g1gfjjuv/3/

Comment: Thanks for help. i did notice change in the library but When i am loading multiple data set into graph i get set of colors which are very loud looking than used by cdnjs older version am charts. So i thought of keeping older version. Thanks :-)

Comment: Sure, check the documentation. At the graph level, there's [lineColor](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#lineColor), [fillColors](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#fillColors), [bulletColor](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletColor), [color](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#color) (for labels) and color properties with `Field` in the name if you want to dynamically specify them your data. You can also create your own themes and/or [colors](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#colors) array.